# C# pause streamreader output after 'x' amount of lines then continue

Tags: c#, loops, ssh, streamreader

I am working on a C# program that implements the SSH.Net library. One of the functions of the program allows for a command to be sent over SSH to the target server and then display the output in a text field.

This works fine, but I am running into an issue when the output response is large.
Currently all the output is displayed until complete. I need a way to , for example show 30 lines, then wait for user input, the show the next 30 lines.

I can easily stop the output at 30 lines with a for loop and a counter, but I am unsure how to start it up again, how to I get back to the same point in the streamreader ?

```
    var list = new List<string>();
                string line;
                output_textBox.Text = String.Empty;

                while (!asynch.IsCompleted)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream))
                    {
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {

                                list.Add(line);
                                Console.WriteLine(line);

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Thanks

EDIT

Got it working with the below.

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream))
                    {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                      {
                          while (line_count < 100 && (line = sr.ReadLine())      != null)
                        {

                            Console.SetOut(new     TextBoxWriter(output_textBox));
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                            line_count++; 
                        }
                          MessageBox.Show("OK to continue"); 
                          line_count = 0; 
                    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `yield return`?

Comment: The content returned from the SSH command could be 1000 lines long, I want to show 100, then wait for user to hit a button/key before continuing with the next 100 lines

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using parallel programming. You can write two functions as Producer & Consumer. For example a producer will continuously read your text and put it in in-memory list, and the consumer will consumed (and remove consumed lines) from the list at your appropriate time interval.

Answer (score 1):

To get back to the line where you finished last time:

```
int startFrom = 30; // skip first 30 lines

using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    // skip lines
    for (int i = 0; i < startFrom ; i++) { 
        rdr.ReadLine();  
    }
    // ... continue with processing file  
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public void Process() { 
    //init
    int startFrom = 0;
    int stepCount = 100;

    //read data  0 - 100
    ReadLines(startFrom, stepCount);
    startFrom += stepCount;

    // after user action
    //read data  100 - 200
    ReadLines(startFrom, stepCount);
}

public void ReadLines( int skipFirstNum, int readNum ) {
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream)) {
        // skip lines
        for (int i = 0; i < skipFirstNum; i++) { 
             rdr.ReadLine();  
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < readNum ; i++) { 
             // ... these are the lines to process
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The content returned from the SSH command could be 1000 lines long, I want to show 100, then wait for user to hit a button/key before continuing with the next 100 lines

Comment: I am not actually reading from a file, it is a SSH response to a command issued on the server

Comment: Thanks ... almost have it like I want now, see updated code. It now displays a text box after 100 lines, the clicking ok makes it continue.